# Angular 2 Protractor: Click div element

Tags: angular, click, protractor, integration-testing, e2e-testing

My html code looks like this:

```html
<div class="btn-login1 btn-login-email" (click)="optionSelected('Email')">
        <i class="fa fa-at fa-fw"></i><span>
            Sign in with Email
        </span>
    </div>
```

Using Protractor, I need to test the click function. I have this code in my test case:

```js
ele = element(by.css('.btn-login1'));
expect(ele).toBeTruthy();
ele.click();
```

When I run the test case, I get this error:

> Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
>   While waiting for element with locator - Locator: By(css selector, .btn-login1)

I have updated the configuration file with the timeout value and still get a similar error about timeout. I believe this could be because a div element is being clicked. My other test case about a button being clicked works fine.

How do I go about writing this test case?

Comment: Do you have many .btn-login1 s or only this div?

Comment: Just this one div.

Comment: Could you move the click on the <i> and check?

Comment: I did. And that didn't help either.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the whole class name? I don't believe much but worth trying

Comment: Done that. Also added an id and tried. No luck.

Comment: Do you have other tests that work well on this same exact page? Sounds like an Angular-to-Protractor sync problem to me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not testing an Angular application you need to set:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Even if it is an Angular Application try this.

I also find I get the best results including the entire attribute when locating elements like:

```
ele = element(by.css('[class="btn-login1 btn-login-email"]'));
```